# Does Node stream.pipeline also provides back-pressuring prevention?

Tags: node.js, stream, backpressure

The answer to this question is perhaps one word. The documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/back-pressuring-in-streams/) is kind of confusing: in the beginning it introduces the `stream.pipeline()` method as even a more preferable version of `.pipe` method, but later on it focuses solely on the .pipe method as a method that provides back-pressuring prevention mechanism. The Node official [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) also clearly mentions `.pipe` as having back-pressuring prevention mechanism, but says no such thing about the `pipeline` method. So: does pipeline (as a supposedly improved version of .pipe) does the same regulating thing to prevent back-pressuring in a pipeline? I hope so. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `pipeline()` handles back pressure.  It's basically `.pipe()` with a LOT better error handling and a more flexible programming interface.