How to handle backpressure in Node streams by queueing each new chunk of data?
I would like to write a function (i.e., the function write shown below) that handles backpressure by queueing each new chunk of data while the stream is draining. Once the stream has drained, then I would like for it to continue writing the data to the stream in the order it was queued. I would like to do this using a async/await pattern as opposed to using a callback.
My implementation is below. I'm wondering if I am doing this right or if I have neglected to handle an important part of the procedure.
import * as stream from 'node:stream';

const transform = new stream.Transform({
    async transform(chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: stream.TransformCallback) {
        callback(null, chunk.toString('utf-8'));
    }
});

stream.pipeline(transform, process.stdout, (err)=>console.error);

const queue: Array<Buffer> = [];

async function write(data: Buffer, encoding?: BufferEncoding): Promise<void> {
    if (!transform.closed) {
        if (!transform.writableNeedDrain) {
            if (queue.length === 0) {
                if (!transform.write(data)) {
                    await new Promise((r)=>transform.once('drain', r));
                }
            }
            else {
                queue.push(data);
            }
            while (queue.length) {
                const data = queue.shift();
                if (data && !transform.write(data)) {
                    await new Promise((r)=>transform.once('drain', r));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            queue.push(data);
        }
    }
}


for (let i = 0; i < 1e1; i++) {
    write(Buffer.from('Something'.repeat(1e1), 'utf-8'));
}


Using the timeout, you are procrastinating on the task. If you want to make a queue and process every chunk in a series, you can leverage Bull.js as the scheduler and the queue manager. Additionally, Bull can provide you with tasks that are spread between different processes.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull

Why not use pipeline?

@Raeisi  The timeout is there to indicate that the code in the transform function will likely cause a lot of backpressure. It's not really relevant to the question; however, I think it's helpful in characterizing what I am inquiring about.

@Inder  If I use pipeline (or pipe), I still need to write to the stream and handle backpressure.  I would like to know if the implementation is handling backpressure correctly.

@Raeisi  I removed the timeout; I can see how that could be confusing.

pipeline handles backpressure automatically. Also there is a promise version if you want to use async await. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781677/18954618

@Inder If a call to write returns false, then it should not be called again until the stream has drained. There are a couple of important reasons for this: (1) It's a potential security vulnerability to call write successively without allowing the stream to drain. (2) Node stream has some internal optimizations that can consume a lot of memory (and hold that memory) if backpressure isn't respected. The pipeline API doesn't eliminate the requirement of handling backpressure.

Yes I'm aware what drain event is for. this is why I suggested to use pipeline which automatically handles backpressure automatically listens for drain and after it is done closes the streams. also provides an error handling mechanism

@Inder  It isn't clear to me what you mean by "automatically handles backpressure".  Even if the pipeline pattern is used, it is still best practice not to write to the stream until it is done draining if the write method returns false.
In this question I am inquiring about if the algorithm that I implemented is properly implemented for the described goal.  Whether I use the pipe pattern or the pipeline pattern isn't relevant.  In the context of both patterns, the stream should not be written to if write returns false; that is why I am queueing the data.

For reference:  https://nodejs.org/en/learn/modules/backpressuring-in-streams

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Inder I refactored the code to use the pipeline pattern (for the sake of best practices); however, as I indicated, I still need to handle backpressure.  I'm just inquiring if my algorithm is correct.
